# Fredholm operators, rank, and closure

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, k-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $D$ be a densely defined symmetric unbounded operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Assume that the kernel and cokernel of $D$ are finite dimensional, and hence that we can assign a well-defined *index* to $D$ by 
$$
Index == Dim(kernel) - Dim(cokernel).
$$ 
Denoting the closure of $D$ by $D^c$, is it true that $D^c$ also has finite dimensional kernel and cokernel? Moreover, is it true that 
$$
Index(D) = Index(D^c)?
$$ 
(Note that the index of $D^c$ is also defined to be the difference in dimensions between its kernel and cokernel.

Comment: What do you mean by Fredholm for arbitrrary operators? Clearly, $ker(D)$ should be finite-dimensional. Do you now assume in addition that the range (not rank!) is closed and finite-codimensional?

Comment: Sorry, I've written it more clearly.

Comment: I don't think this is true because the kernel of $\overline D$ might even be infinite-dimensional. As an example, choose any bounded surjective  operator $A$ with infinite kernel $N$. Now, let $D := A|_{N^\perp}$.

Comment: hmmm . . . so I have now assumed that $D$ is a symmetric operator.

Comment: Argh... Why haven't you done this from the scratch? A densely defined symmetric operator is always closable!

Comment: My apologies for the problems. The assumption that $D$ is closed has now been removed since, as you said, it is implied.

Comment: Say, what is meant by the cokernel of $D$?

Comment: Whatever it is, your claim can only be true when the defect numbers of $S := D^c$ are finite and equal. This follows immediately from the punctured neighborhood theorem (applied to $S$). In particular, $D$ needs to have a selfadjoint extension.

Comment: In any case, I can assure that $S$ has finite-dimensional kernel. Proof: Since $S\subset S^*$, we have $ker S\subset ker S^* = (ran S)^\perp\subset(ran D)^\perp$, which is finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

I guess with $D$ having a finite-dimensional cokernel you mean that $H = ran\,D\dotplus N$ with some finite-dimensional subspace $N$ ($\dotplus$ denoting the direct sum). Actually, I will not answer your question here but try to shed a little more light on the whole thing.

Assuming your hypothesis on $D$, I will show that the index of $D$ must be non-positive and that the closure $S = D^c$ (which is also symmetric) must be Fredholm with also non-positive index.

First, as in the comments above, $ker\,S\subset ker\,S^* = (ran\,S)^\perp\subset(ran\,D)^\perp$. From this we infer $\dim ker\,S < \infty$, but also that
$$
\dim\,(H/ran\,D)\,\ge\,\dim(H/\overline{ran\,D}) = \dim\,(ran\,D)^\perp\,\ge\,\dim ker\,S\,\ge\,\dim ker\,D.
$$
Hence, $ind\,D\le 0$. Also, $ran\,S$ as a superset of $ran\,D$ must be finite-codimensional. By a theorem of Kato, $ran\,S$ is closed. So, $S$ is indeed Fredholm. Moreover,
\begin{align*}
ind\,S
&= \dim ker\,(S) - \dim\,(ran\,(S))^\perp\\
&= \dim ker\,(S) - \dim ker\,(S^*),
\end{align*}
which is non-positive as $ker\,S\subset ker\,S^*$.